# CSS returns "Internal server error" on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.1.1 and have a website with a setting of stylesheets that changes over the year according to seasons etc, like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'themes/theme_winter.css' %>
```

with the `theme_winter.css` is placed in a folder called `themes` in the stylesheet-folder.

I am **using Memcachier** so online it looks like this:

```
<link href="/assets/application-75b2717254d80c8ed37d5f955e2a0287.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/themes/theme_winter-a5de7f8f92d3d03061fd6aeb23ca2c40.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This works perfectly fine on my local machine but on Heroku the winter-stylesheet (and similar) won't load. If I watch the page source and click the link (in the page source, in order to look at the css) I get this error shown in my web browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>Internal Server Error</H1>
    undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    <HR>
    <ADDRESS>
     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09) at
     www.mydomain.com:80
    </ADDRESS>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I can't really see why it is referring to `undefined method` each' for nil:NilClass`. It doesn't make sense!

I believe the problem is related to caches because it used to work before I implemented Memcachier, but I could also remember this wrong.

No matter what, I have tried to add `:cache => false` and uploaded new files with `git add -A` but without any luck.

I really cannot see what is going wrong. I have never seen an error like this in the CSS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911060/fragment-exist-for-memcache-does-not-find-cached-info/), why I do not know. But the problem seems to have been related to me not having memcachier gem installed.