# Fragment_exist for Memcache does not find cached info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I am using Rails, Dalli gem, friendly_id and Memcachier on Heroku.

My problem is similar to [an issue I have had previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724876/cache-only-the-main-content-in-rails) but that stopped working after I started using Memcache instead of the default Rails cache. It should be noted that I am not very familiar with Rails caching and it is quite likely that I do many things wrong (or fail to consider simple things).

**production.rb**

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'mc2.ec2.memcachier.com:11211', { :namespace => 'my_app_name', :expires_in => 40.days, :compress => true, :username => 'asdf', :password => 'asdf' }
```

**Gift#show - controller**

```
unless fragment_exist?("gift-show--" + @gift.slug)
  # Perform slow database fetches etc
end
```

**Gift#show - view**

```
<% cache('gift-show--' + @gift.slug) do %>
 # Create HTML with lots of images and such
<% end %>
```

This worked fine before I started using Memcachier on Heroku. My guess is that `fragment_exist?` does not check in Memcachier but rather in "default Rails cache" (if there is a difference). I have tried to use `Rails.cache.exist?("gift-show--" + @gift.slug)` instead of `fragment_exist?` but it doesn't work.

I have loaded the particular gift#show-view a few times to make sure it is cached. In the logs I can also see `Read fragment views/gift-show--cash-stash (1.3ms)` (after the controller) which I believe is a proof for that a fragment actually exist. It is just that it is going through the slow (4 seconds) gift#show-controller when it is not necessary.

If I enter the console on Heroku and type "`Rails.cache.read('gift-show--cash-stash')`" I get a nil response.

Another peculiar things is that if do the following in the console:

```
irb(main):014:0> Rails.cache.write("foo", "bar")
=> true
irb(main):015:0> Rails.cache.read("foo")
=> nil
```

That is odd, isn't it?

So, what should I use, instead of fragment_exist? in order to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure this is the solution but I **added the 'memcachier' gem** (which I didn't have) and altered my production.rb to:

```
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

This actually also solved another, [completely different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910158/css-returns-internal-server-error-on-heroku), to my great surprise!